# Как вывести индексы непустых Numpy векторов (элементов списка)?

Tags: python, массивы, pandas, numpy, матрицы

Есть список:

```
a = [array([], dtype=float64), array([0.]), array([], dtype=float64)]
```

Нужно из него вывести индексы непустых Numpy векторов

Comment: можете уточнить вопрос? что значит `где array([0.])` ? вы хотите получить индексы непустых numpy векторов в обычном списке?

Comment: Да, получается так. Нужно получить индексы непустых векторов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [9]: a = [array([], dtype=np.float64), array([0.]), array([], dtype=np.float64), array([1.,2.], dtype=np.float64)]

In [10]: a
Out[10]:
[array([], dtype=float64),
 array([0.]),
 array([], dtype=float64),
 array([1., 2.])]

In [11]: res = [i for i,x in enumerate(a) if x.size == 0]

In [12]: res
Out[12]: [0, 2]
```

Comment: Ошибка `NameError: name 'array' is not defined`

Comment: @ChikChirik, `from numpy import array`

Comment: Точно, спасибо!